# Proof that $2\sin(1.5x)\cos(1.5x)=3\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I was looking at the double angle formula which is: $2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ and the triple angle formula which is: $3\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x)$ I was wondering if there is a "easy" proof, something that a pre-calc student could comprehend because saying those two are equal is something that's mindblowing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
2\sin\left(1.5x\right)\cos\left(1.5x\right)&=2\sin \left(\frac{3x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right)\\
\\
&=\sin(3x)\\
\\
&=\sin(x+2x)=\sin x \cos 2x+\sin2x\cos x\\
&=\sin x(1-2\sin^2 x)+2\sin x \cos^2 x\\
&=\sin x(1-2\sin^2 x)+2\sin x (1-\sin^2 x)\\
&=\sin x-2\sin^3 x+2\sin x-2\sin^3 x\\
&=3\sin x-4\sin^3 x \quad \quad \quad\quad \quad \quad\quad \quad \quad\quad \quad \quad \text{Q.E.D}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$2sin(\frac{3x}{2})cos(\frac{3x}{2})=sin(3x)$

Comment: A good first start, but did you try seeing what it gets you beyond 'simplifying' a term?

Comment: I understand the point of converting it to a fraction, it's... I don't know, more precise/easier to understand? But I don't really understand where to go afterwards.

Comment: By De Moivre's THM we have that $cos(3x)+isin(3x)= e^{i3x}=(e^{ix})^{3}=(cos(x)+isin(x))^{3}$. Expanding the expression on the RHS we obtain the desired result